# Find median value of 3 user inputted numbers in C# Without output: Numbers entered: x, y, z Minimum Value: a Median Value: b

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the Median of the three user entered numbers. Please see below code, any help is appreciated and a newbie explanation of why. From what I understand they should be sorted into a list and then the middle number found. I am trying to output the below in a robust way in case I want to ask the user for 4 numbers.

I am trying to output: Numbers entered: x, y, z
Minimum Value: a
Median Value: b

```
using System;

public class Assignment
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int num1; 
        int num2; 
        int num3;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 3 numbers");

        num1 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        num2 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        num3 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Numbers entered: {0}  {1}  {2}", num1, num2, num3);
 if(num1<num2)
    if(num2<num3)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum Value:"+num1);
        }
        else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum Value:"+num3);
        }
        else
        if(num2<num3)
        {
        Console.WriteLine( "Minimum Value:"+num2);
        }
        else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum Value:"+num3 );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code won't compile how it's written right now, but I can see what you're trying to do. You could change it up so it would compile, but it's not the a particularly efficient way of solving it.

Right now, I think you're attempting to write code to check each scenario of the potential order of numbers. You can do it for 3 numbers relatively easy, but what if you want to extend your code to check a list of 10 or 100 numbers?

I think you should add user input to a list, sort the list, then just return the middle value of the list. It's less code and more reliable.

```
public class FindMedian
{
    public List<int> numbersList = new List<int>(); // list to store user input

    // constructor 
    public FindMedian(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter " + n + " numbers. \n\n");

        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number " + i + " : ");

            numbersList.Add(GetUserInput()); // call's GetUserInput
        }

        PrintData();
    }

    // returns int from Console. Will continue to run until a valid int is entered 
    private int GetUserInput() 
    {
        int temp = 0;
        bool numberValid = false;

        while (!numberValid)
        {
            try
            {
                temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                numberValid = true;
            }

            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry. Please try again.\n");
                numberValid = false;
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }

    // prints data after user enteres the correct number of ints 
    private void PrintData()
    {
        // If list contains no data
        if (numbersList.Count < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No User Data Entered");
            return;
        }

        numbersList.Sort(); // Sorts list from smallest to largest

        int minimum = numbersList[0];
        int median;

        // if list count is even and median is average of two middle numbers
        if (numbersList.Count % 2 == 0)
        {
            median = (numbersList[(numbersList.Count / 2) - 2] + numbersList[(numbersList.Count / 2) - 1] / 2);
        }

        // if list count is odd and median is just middle number
        else 
        {
            median = numbersList[(numbersList.Count / 2)];
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Minimum Number : " + minimum);
        Console.WriteLine("Median Number : " + median);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you for the detailed response that is easy to follow. As I am learning the hard way a bracket here and there makes all the difference. Please could you edit your answer so that I can copy and paste it into the code editor and run the program, that way I can backwards engineer. I've tried modifying my version with yours and of course it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Smells like homework

```
int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int num3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
List<int> list1 = new List<int>(); 
list1.Add(num1); 
list1.Add(num2); 
list1.Add(num3); 
Console.WriteLine($"Min:{list.Min()}"); 

list1.Sort();
int c = list1.Count()%2==0?list1.Count()+1:list1.Count();

 int Med = list1[c/2];
//Console.WriteLine($"Max:{list1.Max()");
```

I'm on phone so formatting my code is a hard ..
You can skip the creation of three ints and use a

```
list1.Add(Int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

if you wish or for 'n' numbers

```
bool b = true;
int num=0;
List<int>() l = new List<int>();
Do{
Console.Write("Enter number: ");
 b = 
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num);
    l.Add(num);
    }While(b);
    //insert min, max and median of (List) l here
```

Comment: Hey man, 

Thanks for the answer. It's definitely homework but only our second workshop, we actually haven't had any lessons on it yet. It's a 'find you own solutions' Then be taught how to do it. After a couple hours googling I ended up here. 

I'll give the above a try and see if I can figure it out, it's important to me that I understand it more than getting the right answer.

Comment: I'm on phone, updating my answer is a bit nifty and I rushed it - keep checking updates

Comment: Thanks again, appreciate the help. Will keep checking back.

Comment: Edited.. for n numbers

Comment: No luck my end Daniel, really appreciate the help but could you tell me what I'm looking at and where it should go. I've modified my code but get some errors:

newtest.cs(17,24): error CS8076: Missing close delimiter '}' for interpolated expression started with '{'.
newtest.cs(17,26): error CS1073: Unexpected token '"); '
newtest.cs(17,36): error CS1010: Newline in constant
newtest.cs(17,40): error CS1026: ) expected
newtest.cs(17,40): error CS1002: ; expected
newtest.cs(29,3): error CS1513: } expected

Comment: Edited answer, Ha my autocorrect changed a few things, on desktop now, add `Using System.Linq; Using System.Collections.Generic;` to your using statements

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your help above. I have tried and tried and am still unable to produce the results I need. Are you able to help me further by writing the code so it works. I can then compare it with your first answer and try understand. Right now I do not know enough to be able to get the above code to work